# Iterate over named List in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I have a named list in R:

```
l = list(a=1, b=2)
```

I would like to use this list in Rcpp, and iterate over both the values and the names.  Ideally, it could be something like (using C++11 formatting for the sake of concision):

```
void print_list (List l)
    for (pair < String, int > &p: l)
        cout << p.first << ": " << p.second;
```

Is there a way to do it (even using plain C++)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of these use cases are in fact visible in the unit tests.

Here I am quoting from [tinytest/cpp/Vector.cpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/tinytest/cpp/Vector.cpp):

#### Get names:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector integer_names_get( IntegerVector y ){
    return y.names() ;
}
```

#### Index by name

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int integer_names_indexing( IntegerVector y ){
    return y["foo"] ;
}
```

That should be enough to get you the vector you aim to iterate over.

Comment: If possible, I would like to avoid the "Index by name" step.  I know I will read the entire list, and if I understand correctly, accessing each element by the name would be a waste of time (n(n+1)/2 ?).

Comment: You understand you can iterator over a _every vector_ by position ie index?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the comment (not fluent in English).  Did you mean "You understand you can iterate over every vector by position i.e. index?"  You would mean this: `for (int i=0; i<l.size();i++) cout << l.names()[i] << ": " << l[i];`